# How to do Multiplication in PHP

Tags: php

currently I'm using a open source e-commerce system. I'm trying to add taxes to the total price.

Therefore I multiple the total by 1.13 which is 13% tax, but when I write "*taxtax" after the $totaltotal, it shows the total is $0

```
$totaltotal=price_format($total['amount'], false);
$taxtax=1.13;
$total['amount_formated']  =$totaltotal * $taxtax;
```

Comment: It shows the total price if i delete  *$taxtax

Comment: Pl. check your total price echo $totaltotal; If this is 0 then it right to be return 0 after multiplication.

Comment: do the calculation before the price_format()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
    $tax = 1.13
    $total['amount_formated'] = price_format($total['amount'] * $tax, false)
```

Comment: Hello, it didnt work since price_format($total['amount'], false); returns the total amount, so i need to multiple price_format($total['amount'], false) by 1.13

Comment: Hello, I got a correct answer using your way... i made a mistake

Comment: As told elsewhere, probably `price_format($total['amount'], false);` doesn't return a number: it returns a **string** which, casually, show just digits. If `echo "3 apples" + "3 apples"` return 6, is just because the PHP creators are clever ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Are  you looking for number_format? try this:

```
$total['amount_formated'] =number_format($totaltotal * $taxtax, 2);
```

Comment: Hello, I tried your method, it's showing 0.00 instead of just 0. But still couldn't get the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

If your operating system has strfmon capabilities (i.e. is not Windows, according to the PHP manual page) you can even use the `money_format()` function:

```
$total['amount_formated'] = money_format('%i', $totaltotal * $taxtax);
```

Read more here: https://php.net/money_format

Comment: Hello, I tried your method, it's showing 0.00 instead of just 0. But still couldn't get the correct answer